# urllib2 to open HTTPS

Tags: python, google-analytics, raspberry-pi

I am new to Python, and have no coding background at all. 
I am trying to use my Raspberry Pi to send data to Google Analytics. The problem is that Google Analytics Measurement Protocol usses HTTP**S** - Which my code doesn't work with.

So my current code looks like this

```
import urllib2
import time
import RPi.GPIO as io
io.setmode(io.BCM)


door_sensor = 18
sensorTrigger = True

io.setup(door_sensor, io.IN, pull_up_down=io.PUD_UP)

# function for the door opening
def door_open():
    print("Door Open")
    urllib2.urlopen("https://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&tid=UA- 3458xxxx-1&cid=555&t=event&ec=doors&ea=open&el=office").close

# function for the door closing
def door_close():
    print("Door Close")

while True:
    if io.input(door_sensor): # if door is opened
        if (sensorTrigger):
            door_open() # fire GA code
            sensorTrigger = False # make sure it doesn't fire again
    if not io.input(door_sensor): # if door is closed
        if not (sensorTrigger):
            door_close() # fire GA code
            sensorTrigger = True # make sure it doesn't fire again
```

and the error that I keep getting is...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/pi/Desktop/GADoorSensor.py", line 23, in <module>
door_open() # fire GA code
File "/home/pi/Desktop/GADoorSensor.py", line 14, in door_open
urllib2.urlopen("https://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&tid=UA-3458xxxx-1&cid=555&t=event&ec=doors&ea=open&el=office").close
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 431, in open
response = self._open(req, data)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 449, in _open
'_open', req)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 409, in _call_chain
result = func(*args)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1240, in https_open
context=self._context)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1197, in do_open
raise URLError(err)
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:581)>
```

I followed [THIS](http://nicomiceli.com/tracking-home-google-analytics-part-2-door-sensors/) guide if that helps.

I have read a far few articles online about how to get around this, but because I am new to all this it is beyond confusing.

If someone could give me a hand or direct me towards a beginners guide on how to work this out I would be extremely grateful!

Comment: Have you tried changing `https://` to just `http://`. It should get you around this hurdle of trying to create an encrypted (ssl) connection with urllib2.

Answer (score 0):

I've had better luck with http.client, thusly...

```
import http.client

myDestination = "https://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&tid=UA- 3458xxxx-1&cid=555&t=event&ec=doors&ea=open&el=office"

conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection(myDestination)
```

then use...

```
conn.request()
```

and

```
conn.response()
```

don't forget...

```
conn.close()
```